# How do you resolve unique field clashes in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model that looks like this:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    unique_field = models.URLField(unique=True)
    another_field = models.TextField()
    # etc...
```

and its corresponding ViewSet looks like this (bound to `/foo/`):

```py
class FooViewSet(
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

When I make a POST request to `/foo/`, if there's no clash I just want the default behaviour (create a new row in the database and return its serialized form as a json blob).

The problem is that when there *is* a clash the server just throws an error. What I'd rather have it do is return the json blob for the *existing* data, rather than crashing. Or at the very least return some kind of descriptive error.

Is there a way to get this behaviour without manually overriding `create()`?

Comment: Please add your error.

Comment: Basically, `try: ... except SomeError: ...`

Comment: How does the `FooSerializer` looks like?